# objet title not update in open graph(timeline)

Tags: android

I am working with Facebook's Open graph API,I have created one object-4 hour and action-work its working fine first time after creation of object and post on my Facebook time line like XYZ worked 4 hour on APP NAME

But when I am trying to modify my object title from 4 hour to any other value say 8 hour,it not reflecting on my Facebook its still refer to old value (4 hour).

here is my 4 hour object

http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# healingwithfoods: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/healingwithfoods#">

I have changed sample Fourhour but its not reflecting on my timeline..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Heading ## public String request(String graphPath, Bundle params, String httpMethod)

```
        throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    params.putString("format", "json");
    if (isSessionValid()) {
        params.putString(TOKEN, getAccessToken());
        params.putString("scrape", "true");
    }
    String url = (graphPath != null) ? GRAPH_BASE_URL + graphPath
                                     : RESTSERVER_URL;
    return Util.openUrl(url, httpMethod, params);
}
```

I alredy found answer for android, when you post a data on facebook that time request with one more parameter pass(scrape) and its value is true

I give small portion of code...... it mentioned above...

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-scrape your open graph object anytime it is changed (or wait two weeks for Facebook to do it for you). This can be achieved by running a manual rescrape:

```
curl -X POST \
 -F "id=OG_OBJECT_URL" \
 -F "scrape=true" \
 "https://graph.facebook.com"
```

or by passing in your object URL into the [Open Graph Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: your ans is wright but that is not use for android......i have mentioned belowe..... read it......ok thanks